# CSS only full size background image centered with correct ratio

Tags: css, background

I am looking for a HTML-CSS only solution (no js) to have a background image that would fit its whole container while respecting its ratio and been centered. I'd like the result to be similar to what is achieved here: http://solemone.de/demos/fullsize-background-image-with-css3-background-size/ but without js

The reason why I don't want to use js is because I load the js after everything else and I don't want the user to see an inaccurate background display while loading the page.

Comment: what's wrong with : background-size: auto, cover;  ?

Comment: It seems to not work when the image's width is smaller than the container's with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do. Using CSS3. 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdNYw/)

***CSS3:***

```
html { 
  background: url(path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Works in modern browsers and it scales with the window's size.

Or use CSS only. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gYj72/1/)

***HTML:***

```
<img src="http://wallpapersus.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/cityscapes-city-night-photography-long-exposure.jpg" class="bg" alt="">
```

***CSS:***

```
img.bg 
{
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Its compatible with older and modern browsers.Scales with window's size too.

Note: The way these methods scale the image is to keep the image in nice proportions, in order to look better!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

```
background: url("path/image.png") center center no-repeat;
```

And the size of the background with:

```
background-size: 200px 200px;
```

Background size supports pixel parameter and % parameter.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body
{
    background:url(image.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

`50%` - center background by left, second `50%` - center background by top

`contain` - fit image by object width and height, `cover` - fit image fully by object w/h.